# Why does Rivka have ruach hakodesh at the end of parsha Toldot, but not at the beginning?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment, parashat-toldot

It says in the beginning of Toldos ([Beireshit 25:22-23](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.25.22?lang=bi&aliyot=0)) that Rivka had stomach-aches, so she went to "ask Hashem" about her pregnancy.

[Rashi says](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.25.23.1?lang=bi&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.25.22.4&lang2=bi) that since she didn't have ruach hakodesh, it was actually Shem who told her about Yaakov and Esav.

But at the end of the parsha ([Beireshit 27:42](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.27.42?lang=bi&aliyot=0)), it says "and it was told to Rivka [that Esav wanted to kill Yaakov]", and [Rashi says](https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_Genesis.27.42.1?lang=bi) it was told to her in ruach hakodesh.

So did she get ruach hakodesh later?

Answer (score -2):

According to Rambam's 13 principles (principle 7), Moses as the prophet was special in such a way that only he could "initiate" the prophecy to have 2-way communication with G-d.

All other prophets, including the forefathers (and mothers), could only prophesize when initiated by G-d, so if G-d didn't speak to them they could not do much.

---

*BTW it is very true for other Fathers - why didn't they ask G-d every time they had a doubt - why Abraham and Yitzhok and Yaakov wanted to go down to Egypt without consulting G-d first? THe answer is exactly that - if G-d wanted (in the case with Yitzhok) He instructed him, if no - He didn't.*

Comment: I’m not sure if this fully answers the question. He wanted to know why at the beginning Rivkah needed to ask a proper Navi, but at the end she was perfectly capable of having Ruach HaKodesh on her own. While your answer is technically correct, it’s essentially saying “because it is” - not a very satisfying answer. Do any Mefarshim explain *why* Hashem, so to speak, felt the need to speak with her directly at the end, but not at the beginning?

Comment: That's exactly the point – "she was told" – she didn't ask. Is the question "why G-d spoke to her that time and not another?" 2. רוח הקודש is not a direct talk - it's more like a vision.

Comment: 1. You’ve lost me. 2. And your point is?

Comment: @AlBerko if your answer is true than how could SHem have told her anything?!

Comment: @AlBerko He would have had to Ask Hashem, and according to this comment, only Moshe could have. I'm pretty sure I read somewhere (not sure of the source) that Ruach Hakodesh only rests on men directly, so that's why she had to ask Shem, but then I have the question from the end of the parsha...

Comment: Are you asking whether she was on a higher level at the end than in the beginning, to explain why she didn't have R"H in the beginning but did have it at the end?